# How to restrict entires for one2many field in Openerp

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, openerp-8

When i creating Quotation i need to give only 2 Orderline items.How to restrict them to only 2 entries.Can any one help me?
Thank's in advance

Answer (score 3):

Use the _constraint  in py file.
and in function check the length of the orderlines. and raise an error in case of the more than 2 lines found

Comment: Can you please say me How can i check the number of orderlines

Comment: self_obj = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context);
lenth = len(self_obj.orderline)

Comment: Can u please tell me in which function i need to add these line

Comment: you have to create new function for and add in _constraint . please check addons/product/product.py for ean13 check constraints